# Rotate string HackerRank errors

Tags: python, string

Language: Python

Problem summary: I was at practice rotate string on HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/rotate-string/problem 
and I was coding there on the page and it was telling me that I had a lot of errors.  One was Parse error in pattern: def. But this error and all other errors did not appear when I transferred the code to IDLE.

What I've tried:  I then decided to transfer the code I had done to a python editor IDLE that I was using and then there were no errors and the code worked (almost as intended-I'm still working on it).

This is the same code that I did on the HackerRank page (I know it's not complete yet-I'm a beginner):

```
def printrotation(S):
    n = len(S)
    temp = S + S     
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(temp[i + j], end = ' ')
        print()
S = 'cat'
printrotation(S)
```

Question: Why did I get so many errors for the same code that I placed in IDLE on the page at HackerRank?

Comment: That problem seems to be in the functional programming section, Python is not supported.

Comment: yes I thought that was the case

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may not be select any language in HackerRank page.

**Your code is correct.**

But for that problem you can not use python. Because HackerRank does not support python for that problem.